# NumPy N-dim Array with periodic boundary conditions

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Is it possible to write NumPy N-dim array with periodic boundary conditions as a view?

For example, assume that I have the following initial array:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.arange(2 * 3).reshape((2, 3))
# [[0 1 2]
#  [3 4 5]]
```

Something like:

```
periodic_view(array, shape, offset)
```

resulting in, e.g:

```
new_arr = periodic_view(arr, (4, 5), (0, 0))
# [[0 1 2 0 1]
#  [3 4 5 3 4]
#  [0 1 2 0 1]
#  [3 4 5 3 4]]

new_arr = periodic_view(arr, (4, 5), (1, 1))
# [[5 3 4 5 3]
#  [2 0 1 2 0]
#  [5 3 4 5 3]
#  [2 0 1 2 0]]
```

ans similarly for `symmetric` view.

I know that I could do this via slow direct looping, e.g:

```
import itertools

def periodic_view(arr, shape, offset):
    result = np.zeros(shape, dtype=arr.dtype)
    for i in itertools.product(*tuple(range(dim) for dim in result.shape)):
        slicing = tuple(
            (j - k) % dim
            for j, k, dim in zip(i, offset, arr.shape))
        result[i] = arr[slicing]
    return result
```

I was wondering if there was a way to do this through broadcasting / striding mechanisms.

As a bonus, I would be looking for a solution that can be easily adapted to symmetric (instead of periodic) boundary conditions, e.g:

```
new_arr = symmetric_view(arr, (4, 7), (1, 2))
# [[1 0 0 1 2 2 1]
#  [1 0 0 1 2 2 1]
#  [4 3 3 4 5 5 4]
#  [4 3 3 4 5 5 4]]
```

---

## EDIT

This is similar to [How do I select a window from a numpy array with periodic boundary conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148292/how-do-i-select-a-window-from-a-numpy-array-with-periodic-boundary-conditions) except that in the proposed solution the use of `np.roll()` makes this inconvenient to have an output with a shape larger than the input and it looks like it is copying the data from the input.

---

## EDIT 2

These results can be obtained with `np.pad(mode='wrap')` and `np.pad(mode='symmetric')`, but they are not given as a view.
For symmetric results, there might not be an easy way of using views.
For cyclic results, it seems like there is not one either.

As far as `np.pad()` is concerned, it should be noted that the timings are not as good as other approaches (see my answer).

Comment: In the second `new_arr` why `[2 0 1 2 0]` and not `[1 0 1 2 0]`, it is just a shift along the x axis right?

Comment: No, it is shifting in both axis, since `offset = (1, 1)`; to have shift in only one axis you would use e.g. `offset=(1, 0)`, but then the line should read `[0 1 2 0 1]` and not `[1 0 1 2 0]`). You could easily test that with my slow implementation (which gives correct results).

Comment: Could there be negative offsets?

Comment: @Divakar Yes. I would not see a reason why not including this. In general, it is not so relevant, because you can always bring a negative offset back in trace via the modulus, since it is all periodic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a memory-efficient view is truly not possible (which is probably the case), NumPy offers `np.pad()` which should be as memory-efficient as possible.
While this option allows for great flexibility of the output, supporting a number of padding options, not just cyclic -- through `mode='wrap'`, this seems to be comparatively slow for this use-case, and the code can be made faster in a number of way.
The best compromise in speed and memory-efficiency is by using a view on the result of `np.tile()` after a suitable `np.roll()` (`cyclic_padding_tile_roll()`). Note that the `np.roll()` step can be skipped (`cyclic_padding_tile()`) at the cost of potentially more memory being required, which can also slow down the overall performances.
Alternatively, a memory-efficient and generally fast implementation can be obtained through slicing (`cyclic_padding_slicing()`), which can be significantly slower than other approaches as soon as the base shape is contained many times into the target shape.

---

This is the code for solutions I have tested.
Unless otherwise stated, they should all work for arbitrary dimensions.

The same base code is used for preparing the `offsets` by exploiting the fact that :

```
import numpy as np
import functools
import itertools


def prod(items):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, base_shape)

def reduce_offsets(offsets, shape, direct=True):
    offsets = tuple(
        (offset if direct else (dim - offset)) % dim
        for offset, dim in zip(offsets, shape))
    return offsets
```

**using index looping** (original approach):

```
def cyclic_padding_loops(arr, shape, offsets):
    offsets = reduce_offsets(offsets, arr.shape)
    result = np.zeros(shape, dtype=arr.dtype)
    for i in itertools.product(*tuple(range(dim) for dim in result.shape)):
        slicing = tuple(
            (j + k) % dim
            for j, k, dim in zip(i, offsets, arr.shape))
        result[i] = arr[slicing]
    return result
```

**using `np.tile()` only**
(this uses the same approach as @Divakar but works for arbitrary dimensions):

```
def cyclic_padding_tile(arr, shape, offsets):
    offsets = reduce_offsets(offsets, arr.shape)
    tiling = tuple(
        new_dim // dim + (1 if new_dim % dim else 0) + (1 if offset else 0)
        for offset, dim, new_dim in zip(offsets, arr.shape, shape))
    slicing = tuple(
        slice(offset, offset + new_dim)
        for offset, new_dim in zip(offsets, shape))
    result = np.tile(arr, tiling)[slicing]
    return result
```

**using `np.tile()` and `np.roll()`**:

```
def cyclic_padding_tile_roll(arr, shape, offsets):
    offsets = reduce_offsets(offsets, arr.shape, False)
    tiling = tuple(
        new_dim // dim + (1 if new_dim % dim else 0)
        for offset, dim, new_dim in zip(offsets, arr.shape, shape))
    slicing = tuple(slice(0, new_dim) for new_dim in shape)
    if any(offset != 0 for offset in offsets):
        nonzero_offsets_axes, nonzero_offsets = tuple(zip(
            *((axis, offset) for axis, offset in enumerate(offsets)
            if offset != 0)))
        arr = np.roll(arr, nonzero_offsets, nonzero_offsets_axes)
    result = np.tile(arr, tiling)[slicing]
    return result
```

**using `np.pad()` only**:

```
def cyclic_padding_pad(arr, shape, offsets):
    offsets = reduce_offsets(offsets, arr.shape, False)
    width = tuple(
        (offset, new_dim - dim - offset)
        for dim, new_dim, offset in zip(arr.shape, offsets))
    result = np.pad(arr, width, mode='wrap')
    return result
```

**using `np.pad()` and `np.roll()`**:

```
def cyclic_padding_pad_roll(arr, shape, offsets):
    offsets = reduce_offsets(offsets, arr.shape, False)
    width = tuple(
        (0, new_dim - dim)
        for dim, new_dim, offset in zip(arr.shape, shape, offsets))
    if any(offset != 0 for offset in offsets):
        nonzero_offsets_axes, nonzero_offsets = tuple(zip(
            *((axis, offset) for axis, offset in enumerate(offsets)
            if offset != 0)))
        arr = np.roll(arr, nonzero_offsets, nonzero_offsets_axes)
    result = np.pad(arr, width, mode='wrap')
    return result
```

**using slice looping**:

```
def cyclic_padding_slicing(arr, shape, offsets):
    offsets = reduce_offsets(offsets, arr.shape)
    views = tuple(
        tuple(
            slice(max(0, dim * i - offset), dim * (i + 1) - offset)
            for i in range((new_dim + offset) // dim))
        + (slice(dim * ((new_dim + offset) // dim) - offset, new_dim),)
        for offset, dim, new_dim in zip(offsets, arr.shape, shape))
    views = tuple(
        tuple(slice_ for slice_ in view if slice_.start < slice_.stop)
        for view in views)
    result = np.zeros(shape, dtype=arr.dtype)
    for view in itertools.product(*views):
        slicing = tuple(
            slice(None)
            if slice_.stop - slice_.start == dim else (
                slice(offset, offset + (slice_.stop - slice_.start))
                if slice_.start == 0 else
                slice(0, (slice_.stop - slice_.start)))
            for slice_, offset, dim in zip(view, offsets, arr.shape))
        result[view] = arr[slicing]
    return result
```

**using strides**
(this is substantially @B.M. implementation adapted for n-dim inputs):

```
def cyclic_padding_strides(arr, shape, offsets):
    offsets = reduce_offsets(offsets, arr.shape)
    chunks = tuple(
        new_dim // dim + (1 if new_dim % dim else 0) + (1 if offset else 0)
        for dim, new_dim, offset in zip(arr.shape, shape, offsets))
    inner_shape = tuple(
        x for chunk, dim in zip(chunks, arr.shape) for x in (chunk, dim))
    outer_shape = tuple(
        (chunk * dim) for chunk, dim in zip(chunks, arr.shape))
    inner_strides = tuple(x for stride in arr.strides for x in (0, stride))
    # outer_strides = tuple(x for stride in arr.strides for x in (0, stride))
    slicing = tuple(
        slice(offset, offset + new_dim)
        for offset, new_dim in zip(offsets, shape))
    result = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(
        arr, inner_shape, inner_strides, writeable=False).reshape(outer_shape)
    result = result[slicing]
    return result
```

---

This is the code used for testing:

```
def test_cyclic_paddings(base_shape, shape, offsets, cyclic_paddings):
    print('Base Shape: {},  Shape: {},  Offset: {}'.format(base_shape, shape, offsets))
    arr = np.arange(prod(base_shape)).reshape(base_shape) + 1
    ref_result = cyclic_paddings[0](arr, shape, offsets)
    for cyclic_padding in cyclic_paddings:
        test_result = cyclic_padding(arr, shape, offsets)
        result = np.all(ref_result == test_result)
        if not result:
            print(ref_result)
            print(test_result)
        print(': {:24s} {:4s} '.format(cyclic_padding.__name__, 'OK' if result else 'FAIL'), end='')
        timeit_result = %timeit -o cyclic_padding(arr, shape, offsets)

cyclic_nd_paddings = (
    cyclic_padding_tile,
    cyclic_padding_tile_roll,
    cyclic_padding_pad,
    cyclic_padding_pad_roll,
    cyclic_padding_slicing,
    cyclic_padding_loops,
    cyclic_padding_strides,
)

inputs = (
    ((2, 3), (5, 7), (0, 0)),
    ((2, 3), (5, 7), (0, 1)),
    ((2, 3), (5, 7), (1, 1)),
    ((2, 3), (41, 43), (1, 1)),
    ((2, 3, 4, 5), (7, 11, 13, 17), (1, 2, 3, 4)),
    ((2, 3, 4, 5), (23, 31, 41, 53), (1, 2, 3, 4)),
    ((8, 8), (100, 100), (5, 7)),
    ((80, 80), (8000, 8000), (53, 73)),
    ((800, 800), (9000, 9000), (53, 73)),
)


for (base_shape, shape, offsets) in inputs:
    test_cyclic_paddings(base_shape, shape, offsets, cyclic_nd_paddings)
    print()
```

---

For different inputs, these are the results I get:

```
# Base Shape: (2, 3),  Shape: (5, 7),  Offset: (0, 0)
# : cyclic_padding_tile      OK   6.54 µs ± 70.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_tile_roll OK   6.75 µs ± 29.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad       OK   40.6 µs ± 2.44 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad_roll  OK   42 µs ± 4.49 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_slicing   OK   23 µs ± 693 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_loops     OK   34.7 µs ± 727 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_strides   OK   13.2 µs ± 210 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# Base Shape: (2, 3),  Shape: (5, 7),  Offset: (0, 1)
# : cyclic_padding_tile      OK   6.5 µs ± 223 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_tile_roll OK   19.8 µs ± 394 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad       OK   35.4 µs ± 329 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad_roll  OK   58 µs ± 579 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_slicing   OK   23.3 µs ± 321 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_loops     OK   33.7 µs ± 280 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_strides   OK   13.2 µs ± 194 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# Base Shape: (2, 3),  Shape: (5, 7),  Offset: (1, 1)
# : cyclic_padding_tile      OK   6.68 µs ± 138 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_tile_roll OK   23.2 µs ± 334 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad       OK   30.7 µs ± 236 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad_roll  OK   62.9 µs ± 1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_slicing   OK   23.5 µs ± 266 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_loops     OK   34.6 µs ± 544 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_strides   OK   13.1 µs ± 104 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# Base Shape: (2, 3),  Shape: (41, 43),  Offset: (1, 1)
# : cyclic_padding_tile      OK   8.92 µs ± 63.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_tile_roll OK   25.2 µs ± 185 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad       OK   60.7 µs ± 450 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad_roll  OK   82.2 µs ± 656 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_slicing   OK   510 µs ± 1.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_loops     OK   1.57 ms ± 26.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_strides   OK   18.2 µs ± 639 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# Base Shape: (2, 3, 4, 5),  Shape: (7, 11, 13, 17),  Offset: (1, 2, 3, 4)
# : cyclic_padding_tile      OK   89 µs ± 3.18 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_tile_roll OK   81.3 µs ± 1.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad       OK   106 µs ± 2.77 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad_roll  OK   148 µs ± 9.02 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_slicing   OK   977 µs ± 8.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_loops     OK   18.8 ms ± 342 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_strides   OK   101 µs ± 1.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

# Base Shape: (2, 3, 4, 5),  Shape: (23, 31, 41, 53),  Offset: (1, 2, 3, 4)
# : cyclic_padding_tile      OK   2.8 ms ± 112 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_tile_roll OK   2.05 ms ± 28.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad       OK   6.35 ms ± 237 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad_roll  OK   5.81 ms ± 172 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_slicing   OK   40.4 ms ± 838 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_loops     OK   1.71 s ± 44.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# : cyclic_padding_strides   OK   3 ms ± 64.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# Base Shape: (8, 8),  Shape: (100, 100),  Offset: (5, 7)
# : cyclic_padding_tile      OK   16.3 µs ± 901 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_tile_roll OK   32.6 µs ± 151 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad       OK   65.6 µs ± 229 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad_roll  OK   88.9 µs ± 1.05 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_slicing   OK   333 µs ± 1.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_loops     OK   8.71 ms ± 58.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_strides   OK   25.1 µs ± 255 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

# Base Shape: (80, 80),  Shape: (8000, 8000),  Offset: (53, 73)
# : cyclic_padding_tile      OK   148 ms ± 325 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_tile_roll OK   151 ms ± 1.51 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad       OK   443 ms ± 9.42 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad_roll  OK   442 ms ± 8.64 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# : cyclic_padding_slicing   OK   182 ms ± 469 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
# : cyclic_padding_loops     OK   58.8 s ± 256 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# : cyclic_padding_strides   OK   150 ms ± 534 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# Base Shape: (800, 800),  Shape: (9000, 9000),  Offset: (53, 73)
# : cyclic_padding_tile      OK   269 ms ± 1.11 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# : cyclic_padding_tile_roll OK   234 ms ± 1.39 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad       OK   591 ms ± 3.9 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# : cyclic_padding_pad_roll  OK   582 ms ± 4.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# : cyclic_padding_slicing   OK   250 ms ± 4.43 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# : cyclic_padding_loops     OK   1min 17s ± 855 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
# : cyclic_padding_strides   OK   280 ms ± 2.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting the final desired output as a view of the input is not possible. We can improve though by making a replicated copy along both axes and then slicing. The offset input is to be positive values. The solution would look something along these lines -

```
def periodic_view_repeat_slicing(arr, out_shp, offset):
    M,N = out_shp
    m,n = arr.shape
    o = (m-offset[0])%m,(n-offset[1])%n

    fwd_offset = (M+m-1)//m,(N+n-1)//n
    reverse_offset = (offset[0]+m-1)//m, (offset[1]+n-1)//n
    p,q = fwd_offset[0]+reverse_offset[0], fwd_offset[1]+reverse_offset[1]

    arrE = np.tile(arr,(p,q))
    out = arrE[o[0]:o[0]+M,o[1]:o[1]+N]
    return out
```

Comment: thanks for the input, but here the intermediate *tiled* array can be way larger than needed, e.g. if `out_shp` is very similar to `arr.shape` then `arrE` is `2 ** arr.ndim` large.

Comment: @norok2 `arrE` would be `arr.size*4` at most in those very similar shapes cases iff when the offset doesn't allow slicing to get the output.

Comment: that is because `arr.ndim == 2` and hence `2 ** arr.ndim == 4`... for 2-dims this may still be kind of OK, but for larger dimensions, this is going to be quite relevant.

Comment: @norok2 Yeah, an alternative would be slicing+stacking. But that would be complicated when we are talking about ndim>2.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using [as_strided](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided.html)

```
import numpy as np
a0=np.arange(2 * 3).reshape((2, 3))

from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

def periodic_view(array, shape, offset):
    ox,oy = offset
    stx,sty = array.strides    
    shx,shy = array.shape   
    nshx,nshy = shape
    nx = (nshx+ox-1)//shx +1 #enough room, with offset<shape.
    ny = (nshy+oy-1)//shy +1
    big_view=as_strided(a0,(nx,shx,ny,shy),(0,stx,0,sty)).reshape(nx*shx,ny*shy)
    return big_view[ox:,oy:][:nshx,:nshy]
```

Try :

```
a=periodic_view(arr,(4,5),(1,1))

a
Out[211]: 
array([[4, 5, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 0, 1, 2],
       [4, 5, 3, 4, 5],
       [1, 2, 0, 1, 2]])

a.flags
Out[212]: 
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

But it's not a view, you don't write on original array if you  modify the result.

Comment: Memory-wise this is even worse than with tiling: `a.nbytes == 160` but `a.base.nbytes == 1728`!

Comment: If I understand correctly how this works, the critical step preventing from getting a memory-efficient view is the `.reshape()` step after `as_strided()`. With this in mind I believe that this is actually the same as using `np.tile()` because a memory-expensive copy will be created the same way.